# Atualizar atributo salario no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

tô tendo dificuldade na função UPDATE, em que eu preciso fazer uma alteração de - 10% na Tabela DEPARTAMENTO onde o atributo Salario  é da tabela FUNCIONARIO e Dnome de DEPARTAMENTO eu estou tentando assim:

```
 UPDATE DEPARTAMENTO,FUNCIONARIO
 SET Salario = Salario - (Salario * 0.10)
 WHERE Dnome = 'Administração';
```

O que eu quero fazer é Modificar os salários de todos os funcionários do departamento ‘Administração’, retirando 10 por cento de cada salário.

Esta dando o erro 1175. " You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table whitouth  a WHERE that uses a key column . To disable safe mode toggle the option in prefferences --> Editor and  Reconnect "

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Esta é apenas uma proteção setada pelo editor que está usando (talvez o MySQL Workbench?)

**Vale notar que você está mexendo com duas tabelas sem explicitar o tipo de `join` usado, a proteção pode ser até adequada ao seu caso.**

Alguns editores setam a opção

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

que vale para a conexão atual. Isto faz com que tentativas de alteração sem colunas com índice no `WHERE` sejam recusadas, para evitar modificações extensas por acidente.

Soluções mais comuns:

- usar um `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` na conexão atual
- alterar as preferências da ferramenta utilizada para que ela não ative a proteção
- ou mesmo indexar a referida coluna (mas isso somente se for benéfico para a aplicação como um todo)

Mais detalhes no manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates

Esta leitura pode ajudar:

[Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/70)